# Aquamacs on OS X spawns too many GTAGS process whenever I do a findtags

Tags: macos, emacs, ctags, aquamacs

Aquamacs on mac spawns too many GTAGS process whenever I do a find tags, like 5 or 6 more, I have to kill them manually. I tried the nightly build Aquamacs 3.3, same. Any idea how to fix this?

the normal emacs build doesn't have this problem, it does spawn GTAGS too, but up to two.

thanks
patrick